# Integrate package (JAR) and force my app to use this particular package/instance

Tags: android, gson, jackson

Sorry for my terminology, but here is how it goes.

I added GSON package JAR to my Android application and all was well until my app started to fail on some HTC devices - here is summary:
http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=255

So, in order to fix that - I had to get GSON sources and embed those into my app while renaming all namespaces. Time consuming and hard to upgrade now.

So, anyway. I'm thinking about switching to Jackson for my JSON parsing needs and I wonder how to possibly avoid similar issue. Is there any way to tell my app to explicitly use JAR that came with it? I'm not sure how it works but hopefully you get an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to tell my app to explicitly use JAR that came with it?

Sorry, but no. You do not control the classpath. The firmware always wins.

Most of the time, this will occur because Android itself has the third-party JAR as part of what gets loaded into each virtual machine. The Legion of the Bouncy Castle is a great example of this.

This is the first I've encountered where a device manufacturer appears to have added third-party classes to what gets loaded in each virtual machine. I will contact them and ask them to stop doing this, though I have no idea if they will listen.

Comment: So if I want to stay away from same potential issue with Jackson - I have no choice but rename it's namespace?

Comment: @katit: Frankly, I wouldn't worry about it until and unless you encounter problems. Google is unlikely to be integrating Jackson into Android proper, and, as I noted, this does not happen very often.

Comment: There is some irony there -- android bundling a package makes it much harder to use that package, since it's hard to upgrade it to a new version for example. :-/